# Fastest way to extract DataTable from bigger DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable

Let's say I have a table in this structure

```
Id | Name | Product
-------------------
1   Name1   Product1
1   Name1   Product2
2   Name3   Product3
3   Name4   Product4
```

The table is ordered by Id in the sql query which returns it.
Now, I want to extract DataTable containing the specified rows for each unique id.
This means that using the above example, I should get three DataTables containing the rows with different Id valus.

Comment: You'd need to iterate over every row anyway. You should try sending another SQL query instead of searching within already fetched results.

Comment: what should be your output like ????

Comment: What do you want to do with Product? First (MIN), Last (MAX), Count? Sounds like you should do it in the SQL query before it hits the data table.

Comment: Try using Common Table Expressions and get the data from the server. Unless you need all the (unfiltered) data, this is would be the fastest way.

Answer (score 1):

You should use DataView.RowFilter() to get it fast. Please refer [**DataTable.Select() Vs DataView.RowFilter() Performance Test – Filtering Rows**](http://csharp-guide.blogspot.in/2012/05/datatableselect-vs-dataviewfilter.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use a DataView.

```
var view = new System.Data.DataView(table);
view.Sort = "id";

foreach(var id in new [] {1,2,3})
{
    view.RowFilter = "id = " + id.ToString();
    var result = view.ToTable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `linq` to achieve this with a `datatable`, ***something*** like the below (*which is by no means tried and tested*):

```
var groupedResults= from r in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                  group r by r.Field<string>("Id") into g
                  select new
                  {
                      Id = g.Key,
                      Name = g.Min(),
                      Product = g.Count()
                  };
```

The most efficient way would probably be straight SQL before the datatable:

```
SELECT Id, Name, MIN(Product)
FROM [Your_Table]
GROUP BY Id, Name
```

This sample takes the first `Product`.

To get a `Count` of Products do something like:

```
SELECT Id, Name, COUNT(Product)
FROM [Your_Table]
GROUP BY Id, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
string expression = "Id = yourId";
DataRow[] foundRows = originalTable.Select(expression);
```